# Inconcistencies with Debian packages, executing from path, listing with dpkg and looking derivative utilities except apt

Tags: debian, apt, dpkg

Self-explanatory:

```
$ npm
npm: archivo no encontrado (file not found)
$ whereis npm
npm:
$ which npm
$ apt list npm
Listando... Hecho (listing, done)                   
npm/stretch-backports 5.8.0+ds6-2~bpo9+1 all
```

But dpkg:

```
$dpkg -L npm
dpkg-query: el paquete `npm' no está instalado.
Utilice dpkg --info (= dpkg-deb --info) para           
examinar archivos,
y dpkg -
```

What's happening on this install? Which program is lying? I know it's dpkg, but why?

Surely there's something wrong on the bottom since:

```
$sudo apt-get install npm
Leyendo lista de paquetes... Hecho
Creando árbol de dependencias       
Leyendo la información de estado... Hecho
No se pudieron instalar algunos paquetes. Esto puede significar que
usted pidió una situación imposible o, si está usando la distribución
inestable, que algunos paquetes necesarios aún no se han creado o se
han sacado de «Incoming».
La siguiente información puede ayudar a resolver la situación:
Los siguientes paquetes tienen dependencias incumplidas:
 npm : Depende: nodejs (>= 6.11~) pero 4.8.2~dfsg-1 va a ser instalado
       Depende: node-abbrev (>= 1.1.1~) pero 1.0.9-1 va a ser instalado
       Depende: node-ansi-regex (>= 3.0~) pero 2.0.0-1 va a ser instalado
       Depende: node-cacache (>= 10.0.4~) pero no va a instalarse
       Depende: node-config-chain (>= 1.1.11~) pero no va a instalarse
       Depende: node-glob (>= 7.1.2~) pero 7.1.1-1 va a ser instalado
       Depende: node-hosted-git-info (>= 2.6~) pero 2.1.5-1 va a ser instalado
       Depende: node-ini (>= 1.3.5~) pero 1.1.0-1 va a ser instalado
       Depende: node-npm-package-arg pero no va a instalarse
       Depende: node-jsonstream (>= 1.3.2~) pero 1.0.3-4 va a ser instalado
       Depende: node-libnpx (>= 10.0.1~) pero no va a instalarse
       Depende: node-lockfile (>= 1.0.3~) pero 0.4.1-1 va a ser instalado
       Depende: node-lru-cache (>= 4.1.1~) pero 4.0.2-1 va a ser instalado
       Depende: node-move-concurrently (>= 1.0.1~) pero no va a instalarse
       Depende: node-normalize-package-data (>= 2.4~) pero 2.3.5-2 va a ser instalado
       Depende: node-gyp (>= 3.6.2~) pero 3.4.0-1 va a ser instalado
       Depende: node-resolve-from (>= 4.0~) pero 2.0.0-1 va a ser instalado
       Depende: node-npmlog (>= 4.1.2~) pero 0.0.4-1 va a ser instalado
       Depende: node-osenv (>= 0.1.5~) pero 0.1.0-1 va a ser instalado
       Depende: node-read-package-json (>= 2.0.13~) pero 1.2.4-1 va a ser instalado
       Depende: node-request (>= 2.83~) pero 2.26.1-1 va a ser instalado
       Depende: node-retry (>= 0.10.1~) pero 0.6.0-1 va a ser instalado
       Depende: node-rimraf (>= 2.6.2~) pero 2.5.4-2 va a ser instalado
       Depende: node-semver (>= 5.5~) pero 5.3.0-1 va a ser instalado
       Depende: node-sha (>= 2.0.1~) pero 1.2.3-1 va a ser instalado
       Depende: node-slide (>= 1.1.6~) pero 1.1.4-1 va a ser instalado
       Depende: node-strip-ansi (>= 4.0~) pero 3.0.1-1 va a ser instalado
       Depende: node-tar (>= 4.4~) pero 2.2.1-1 va a ser instalado
       Depende: node-boxen (>= 1.2.1~) pero no va a instalarse
       Depende: node-latest-version (>= 3.0~) pero no va a instalarse
       Depende: node-which (>= 1.3~) pero 1.2.11-1 va a ser instalado
E: No se pudieron corregir los problemas, usted ha retenido paquetes rotos.
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that anyone is lying :)

`stretch-backports` release just has a lower priority (`apt-cache policy npm` will show that) and You have to specify it explicitly:

```
sudo apt-get -t stretch-backports install npm
```